# Ruby send mail with DSN

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, report, smtpclient

Using gem [mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail) and considering http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/dsn.html I want to do something like this:

```
mail = Mail.new
mail.delivery_method :smtp, :address => 'smtp.server.com', :port => 25
mail.from = 'sender@smtp.server.com'
mail.to = '<recipient@yet.another.server.com> NOTIFY=SUCCESS ORCPT=rfc822;recipient@yet.another.server.com'
mail.deliver!
```

And I get error:

```
...ruby/2.1.0/net/smtp.rb:957:in `check_response': 501 5.1.3 Bad recipient address syntax (Net::SMTPSyntaxError)
```

Then I try monkey-patching (I know it's dirty):

```
class Net::SMTP
  def rcptto(to_addr)
    if $SAFE > 0
      raise SecurityError, 'tainted to_addr' if to_addr.tainted?
    end
    # REPLACE
    # getok("RCPT TO:<#{to_addr}>")
    # WITH
    getok("RCPT TO:<#{to_addr}> NOTIFY=SUCCESS,FAILURE,DELAY ORCPT=rfc822;#{to_addr}")
  end
end
```

and it works fine but it's ugly (

Does anyone know more legal and beauty solution?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation from source code](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/mail.rb#L44) and [README page](https://github.com/mikel/mail#making-an-email-have-it-your-way) on GitHub, you need to do something like that:

```
mail = Mail.new
mail.delivery_method :smtp, address: 'smtp.server.com', port: 25
mail[:from] = 'sender@smtp.server.com'
mail[:to]   = '<recipient@yet.another.server.com> NOTIFY=SUCCESS ORCPT=rfc822;recipient@yet.another.server.com'
mail.deliver!
```

May be more elegant way would be:

```
mail = Mail.new do
  from 'sender@smtp.server.com'
  to '<recipient@yet.another.server.com> NOTIFY=SUCCESS ORCPT=rfc822;recipient@yet.another.server.com'
end

mail.delivery_method :smtp, address: 'smtp.server.com', port: 25

mail.deliver!
```

Comment: What is the difference between `mail.from = 'sender@smtp.server.com'` and `mail[:from] = 'sender@smtp.server.com'`? [Documentation](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/message.rb#L81-L99) says it's the same

Comment: @user3309314, you are right. No difference. I didn't see that.